# Apache http 2.2.29 does not log anything to access log on RHEL 5 platform

Tags: linux, apache, rhel5

I have a setup which has Apache-2.2.29 compiled against Openssl-0.9.8zb on RHEL5 platform. Apache successfully creates the access log file but it does not logs anything to it.

I have tried with default access log file ( CustomLog logs/access_log combined ) and custom defined ( CustomLog logs/testaccess_log combined ) to ensure its not a permission problem. The log file gets created successfully when the server is started but the server does not logs anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble guys, I just noticed that my server ran out of disk space and that's why apache wasn't logging anything except the error logs.

Managed to clear some disk space and everything is back to normal !!